# How to trigger a refresh event?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

From https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/:

> You can force a bean to refresh its configuration (that is, to pull updated values from the Config Server) by annotating the MessageRestController with the Spring Cloud Config @RefreshScope and then triggering a refresh event.

How can we trigger this refresh event (for classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@RefreshScope`)? We don't want to use the spring actuator `/refresh` endpoint.
What is necessary here, that the application fetches the config from configserver?

Answer (score 10):

You can fire a `RefreshEvent` using an autowired `ApplicationEventPublisher`. Spring Cloud has a listener for this event in `RefreshEventListener`

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

public void fireRefreshEvent() {
  eventPublisher.publishEvent(new RefreshEvent(this, "RefreshEvent", "Refreshing scope");
}
```

References:

[1st Reference](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/endpoint/event/RefreshEventListener.java)

[2nd reference](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/endpoint/event/RefreshEvent.java)

Comment: missing a closing brace there inside fireRefreshEvent() 

Answer (score 2):

`RefreshEndpoint` bean can be autowired and used to refresh cloud configurations

Answer (score 0):

To refresh your configuration properties  to all of your microservices you can message broker ( Spring cloud bus ) through that you can publish the changes to all of your microservices.

Reference:

https://springbootdev.com/2018/07/17/spring-cloud-config-refreshing-the-config-changes-with-spring-cloud-bus-part-2/

Comment: We already have an implementation for receiving a trigger in the service instance, that a config change might have occured. We just need to know, how to programmatically trigger the instance then to contact the configserver and fetching the new config (which is working via http we think).

Comment: Yeah it's just a HTTP call. Then for that add a `@Component`  class in your config server and add a `@PostConstruct` method. In that method fetch the all services from service discovery using discovery client and hit the refresh endpoint in all specific microservices.

Comment: But how can we trigger this call from client instance to config server programmatically (basically what `/refresh` on the actuator endpoint would do)?

Comment: /refresh endpoint will do re call the config-server, so that newly updated properties will resides to your microservice.

Comment: yeah, but can we avoid using the `/refresh` endpoint? Can we programmatically trigger the same what this endpoint is doing? Do you know which bean we have to inject and use here?

Comment: Just thing how can you do this, without calling the config server after calling the config server you will get the latest configured l configuration from that.