# Spring Boot force reload DB connection on INI file read

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an application with a UI which will manage some facets of a Spring Boot application while it is live.

First of all, there will be an INI file name passed in when the application starts which will have a username, password and host for the DB connection.

I have successfully implemented this dynamic database capability by starting the Spring Boot application after the initial INI file load.
However, I need to be able to change the @Primary data source on-the-fly during execution.

The user will click a button in the UI, the INI file will load from a specified source in the UI and I want the DB connection to drop, switch to the new properties read in from the INI file and restart the connection.

It seems to me that @RefreshScope + actuator method will not work for me since I am refreshing from a UI in the application and not an endpoint.

AbstractRoutingDatasource seems like it requires you to know the DB connection properties for the various sources at compile time and furthermore it's a lot more complex than I think is necessary to solve a simple problem such as this.  I would think there should be some class which will allow a simple reload by telling it to call `getDataSource` again and reinitialize.

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "smsEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "smsTransactionManager",
        basePackages = { "com.conceptualsystems.sms.db.repository" })
public class JpaConfig {
    @Bean(name="SMSX")
    @Primary
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error("DATABASE INITIALIZING: getDataSource() called!");

        DataSourceBuilder builder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        builder.driverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        builder.username(IniSettings.getInstance().getIniFile().getDbUser());
        builder.password(IniSettings.getInstance().getIniFile().getDbPassword());
        String host = IniSettings.getInstance().getIniFile().getDbPath();
        String db = IniSettings.getInstance().getIniFile().getDbName();
        String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + host + ";databaseName=" + db;
        logger.info("Connecting [" + connectionString +"] as [" +
                IniSettings.getInstance().getIniFile().getDbUser() + ":" +
                IniSettings.getInstance().getIniFile().getDbPassword() + "]");
        builder.url(connectionString);
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "smsEntityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean smsEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("SMSX") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .persistenceUnit("smsEntityManagerFactory")
                .packages("com.conceptualsystems.sms.db.entity")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "smsTransactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager smsTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("smsEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

main entry point:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel( new FlatLightLaf() );
    } catch( Exception ex ) {
        System.err.println( "Failed to initialize LaF" );
    }

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowSplash());

    System.out.println("Scrap Management System v" + VERSION);

    String iniFilename = null;
    String user = null;
    String pass = null;

    for(String arg : args) {
        if(arg.startsWith(ARG_HELP)) {
            System.out.println(HELP_TEXT);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(arg.startsWith(ARG_INI)) {
            iniFilename = arg.substring(ARG_INI.length());
            System.out.println("User entered INI file location on command line: " + iniFilename);
        }
        if(arg.startsWith(ARG_USER)) {
            user = arg.substring(ARG_USER.length());
            System.out.println("User entered DB username on command line: " + user);
        }
        if(arg.startsWith(ARG_PSWD)) {
            pass = arg.substring(ARG_PSWD.length());
            System.out.println("User entered DB password on command line: [****]");
        }
    }

    mIniFile = new IniFile(iniFilename);

    try {
        mIniFile.load();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error loading INI file!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    IniSettings.getInstance().setIniFile(mIniFile);
    System.out.println("INI file set completed, starting Spring Boot Application context...");

    SplashFrame.getInstance().enableSiteSelection();

    mApplicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Main.class)
            .web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)
            .headless(false)
            .bannerMode(Banner.Mode.LOG)
            .run(args);

    try {
        IniSettings.getInstance().setIniSource(new IniJPA());
        IniSettings.getInstance().load();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to setup INI from database!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can trigger a refreshEvent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105699/how-to-trigger-a-refresh-event

Comment: `@RefreshScope` will work and isn't related to an endpoint. You could even have a file watcher and when detecting a change automatically refresh. If this is a Spring Boot application you only need to configure your `DataSource` the rest you can use from auto configuration.